# Processing: Increment a counter when midpoint of ellipses are passed

Tags: processing

I've got some code that displays 10 ellipses in random locations on the screen, and a square that descends from the top of the screen to the bottom, at which point it resets back at the top. What I'm trying to do is get a counter to increment when that square passes any of the ellipses (by comparing their y-positions). However, the counter increases rapidly instead of steadily and just doesn't behave desirably in general.

Here's my `draw()` function. `barriers[i][0]` stores the x-pos, `barriers[i][1]` the y-pos obviously.

```java
void draw()
{
  background(255);
  fill(0);

  for(int i = 0; i < barriers.length; i++) {
    // Draw barriers
    ellipse(barriers[i][0], barriers[i][1], 50, 50);

    // Did we pass a barrier? (doesn't work!)
    if(y >= barriers[i][0] - 1 && y <= barriers[i][1] + 1) {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  // Draw the square
  rect(x, y, 25, 25);

  // Draw counter alongside square
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text(counter, x + 25, y - 5);

  // Reset
  if(y < height) {
    y+=5;
  } else {
    y = -25;
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Apologies if the solution is blindingly obvious, but I'm just not seeing the problem here...

Looking forward to some assistance.

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mcve]. We can't run this code because you haven't included the declaration or initialization of many of these variables, so we have no idea what their values should be.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this section of code:

```java
if(y >= barriers[i][0] - 1 && y <= barriers[i][1] + 1) {
  counter++;
}
```

The `draw()` function fires 60 times a second, so this code will be fired 60 times per second. That means that **while you're passing a barrier, the `counter` variable will increment 60 times per second!**

Presumably you only want the counter to increase **once** for each barrier. There are a number of ways to do this. You could have another data structure that keeps track of whether each barrier has already been passed, and then only check barriers that haven't been passed yet. Or you could keep track of the previous positions of the square, and then use that to determine when the square starts passing a barrier.

Think about how you would do this in your head, without a computer. How do you know when the square is passing a circle? How do you, in your head, only count one for each barrier?

Answer (score 0):

Following [Kevin's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585400/processing-increment-a-counter-when-midpoint-of-ellipses-are-passed/37592587#37592587), I was able to get it working using an array of booleans which I used to ensure I wasn't incrementing `counter` more than once:

Full code:

```
float barriers[][] = new float[10][2];
float x = 400;
float y = -25;
int counter = 0;
boolean barriersChecked[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

void setup()
{
  size(800, 600); 
  genBarriers();
}

void genBarriers()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < barriers.length; i++) {
    barriers[i][0] = random(width);
    barriers[i][1] = random(height);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  fill(0);

  for (int i = 0; i < barriers.length; i++) {
    // Draw barriers
    ellipse(barriers[i][0], barriers[i][1], 50, 50);

    // Did we pass a barrier?
    if (barriers[i][1] < y && !barriersChecked[i]) {
      counter++;
      barriersChecked[i] = true;
    }
  }

  // Draw the square
  rect(x, y, 25, 25);

  // Draw counter alongside square
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text(counter, x + 25, y - 5);

  // Reset
  if (y < height) {
    y+=2;
  } else {
    y = -25;
    genBarriers();

    // Reset barriersChecked
    for(int i = 0; i < barriersChecked.length; i++) {
      barriersChecked[i] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Out of curiosity, is there a more elegant (loopless) way of resetting every element in `barriersChecked` back to `false`?

Suggestions of additional improvements would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as a question in a new post, not an answer. But you could just reinitialize the array, since the default value is false.